# Error when calling MvcHttpHandler.ExecuteRequest from custom IHttpHandler

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, ihttphandler

I have a custom IHttpHandler that calls MvcHttpHandler implemented as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2968460/170190).

It worked well in asp.net MVC2, but after I migrate the code to MVC4 with IISExpress 7.5, I start getting InvalidOperationException on the line:

```
httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

with message:

> 'HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before
>   'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.

ASP.NET Development Server does not make any problems.

Does anyone know what's going on here, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need to use `httpContext.Server.TransferRequest` with the MVC update.

See this question: [MVC3 Application Inside Webforms Application Routing is throwing a HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior Error in IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639822/mvc3-application-inside-webforms-application-routing-is-throwing-a-httpcontext-s)

Comment: I tried that one, but it doesn't work. I believe it's because there is no place where I tell system to use MvcHandler to process the requested path.

Comment: I replaced these two lines:

IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);

With:

HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(Request.ApplicationPath);

And it worked great!

Comment: I'm getting the same errors after upgrading our application from MVC 2 to MVC 5.  Unfortunately, there is a place where `Server.TransferRequest` generates an error and cannot be used a replacement.  Are there other options?

My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533724/execute-multiple-controller-actions-in-one-call-with-mvc-net-5