# Get exception in httpHandler.ProcessRequest in Default.aspx.cs after migrating MVC4 to MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I converted an MVC4 app to MVC5 in VS2013. I installed MVC5 via NuGet and followed the tips listed on http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2.

But when I try to run the app it gives me an error in Default.aspx.cs:

> 'HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before
>   'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.

Hoping someone has seen this before.

Comment: Please check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998664/error-when-calling-mvchttphandler-executerequest-from-custom-ihttphandler